# Fire hover event on page load - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a CSS hover event for each letter. On hover it increases its size and on mouseleave, its back to normal.
I would like to show the same effect on page load.
When page loads, 'H' will zoom in & out & then 'E' & then 'L'......one after the other

Here is what I tried but didnt work - http://jsfiddle.net/vrm0bve1/

**HTML:**

```
<span class="char1 animate">H</span>
<span class="char2 animate">E</span>
<span class="char3 animate">L</span>
<span class="char4 animate">L</span>
<span class="char5 animate">0</span>
```

**CSS**

```
     .animate {    
    font-size:14px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 1s;
    -moz-transition: font-size 1s;
    -ms-transition: font-size 1s;
    -o-transition: font-size 1s;
    transition: font-size 1s;
}
.animate:hover {
    font-size: 3.5em;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".char1").trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseleave');
$(".char2").trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseleave');
$(".char3").trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseleave');
$(".char4").trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseleave');
$(".char5").trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseleave');
```

Comment: See my answer below for without using any plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WOW.js for this.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aogmva0h/3/)

HTML:

```
<span class="animated wow" data-wow-delay="1s">H</span>
<span class="animated wow" data-wow-delay="2s">E</span>
<span class="animated wow" data-wow-delay="3s">L</span>
<span class="animated wow" data-wow-delay="4s">L</span>
<span class="animated wow" data-wow-delay="5s">0</span>
```

CSS:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomInOut;
          animation-name: zoomInOut;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomInOut {
  0% {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@keyframes zoomInOut {
  0% {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
new WOW().init();
```

Make sure to include WOW.js plugin.

Answer (score 1):

**Without using any extra plugin**:

You can do it with the concept of closure like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  
    
var span = $("span[class]");    
for(var i=0; i<span.length;i++){
animate = function(x){
   //console.log(x); 
   setTimeout(function(){
       x.addClass("scale").prev().removeClass("scale");
       

   }, i*2000);   

};
    
animate(span.eq(i));    
    

};    

});
```

```css
.animate {

    font-size:14px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 1s;
    -moz-transition: font-size 1s;
    -ms-transition: font-size 1s;
    -o-transition: font-size 1s;
    transition: font-size 1s;
}
.scale {
    font-size: 3.5em;
}

.animate:hover{
    font-size: 3.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="char1 animate">H</span>
<span class="char2 animate">E</span>
<span class="char3 animate">L</span>
<span class="char4 animate">L</span>
<span class="char5 animate">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/wafacawumi/edit?html,output

Recursive version. WOW.js is cool, but is that worth pollutting your js with all the features you won't use?

Comment: It is very small library and he can use this for other animations. jQuery which you use in your code is 10 times bigger ;)

Comment: haha, kidding? wow.js 8.23 Kbs minified and depends on animate.css file! How 10 lines of code can be bigger than 2 requests and almost 10Kbs of code?

Comment: $(".char1").trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseleave');
and he was already using jquery, while you added another level of complexity to his project =) that's IMHO.

Comment: Okay, maybe you are right. By the way it does not depend on animate.css, i didn't include this in my example.

Comment: well, that's okay - I referred to their github page, they pointed it as dependency. Anyway - UI/front-end main rule to "live on the top of food chain" using already existing and well-tested solutions. So your version is quite good enough. If I was under pressure of releasing something in 30 minutes - I'd rather picked wow.js and forgot about it cause I would be sure it won't break anything. 

Anyway - for a such a trivial problem, it's possible to use existing vocabulary and framework to solve. No one is wrong among us, both of solutions are working anyway =)

Comment: I agree, it depends on what you are looking for. I'm assuming that he doesn't want to build a website with just a word "Hello", it must be something bigger :) With todays speed of internet i think influence of this plugin on page loading will be ~0. But there are sites where every milisecond is important and there - your solution is better. Sorry for bad english :)